# What is `window.BrowserConfig`?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm looking at some JavaScript code I found online and I see references to `window.BrowserConfig`. I've been unable to find anything about this online. Exploring with the respective JS consoles, I see it's undefined in FF and Safari, but defined in Chrome.

Anyone know what it's for and what we can do with it?

Answer (score 1):

You must be confusing with `browserconfig.xml`, which use to be loaded with `javascript` into the webpage. It is used by **Windows 8** and **Windows Phone** to parse the data to integrate in a nice way on the Metro Interface (getting statistics, an icon and so on..)

But sorry, I'm pretty sure that `window.BrowserConfig` does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the dev tools in Chrome say otherwise.

Comment: Well my fault then. Can you please send me the link?

Comment: @JohnK In what page or extension are you trying this? It's `undefined` in Chrome here at stackoverflow.com.

Comment: See Kayak.com: it's referenced in the r9.js script.

Comment: This is definitely one of their own variable. I request once more the Chrome official dev tools reference please

Comment: @JohnK They are defining it themselves. Within that file you'll find `BrowserConfig=window.BrowserConfig||{};`. This should either set it back to itself if it's already been set or define it to be an empty `Object`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski, I saw that. But that would appear to make  `BrowserConfig` a new variable set to the value of `window.BrowserConfig`, which still leaves the latter unexplained.

Comment: @JohnK Both sides of the `=` are trying to refer to the same global variable. Since `window` is the global object in browsers and [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators) don't throw `ReferenceError`s, `window.BrowserConfig` is a "*safe*" read of the variable. If it's been declared before this, then the assignment doesn't do much -- just assigns it back to itself. But, if this is the 1st use, it can declare and set it to an empty `Object`.

Comment: I appreciate your replies, guys. I'm thinking of deleting my question. Any objections?

Comment: @JohnK no problem, it's good to be curious.
Doon't cancel your question, it was a question, threre is an answer. Accept my answer pls ;)
If everybody would cancel their question when they guessed wrong, we wouldn't find anything on SO... :o It may help for someone else encountering that !